# How to fix Unknown column 'i' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql

Unknown column 'i' in 'field list'

```
for (int i = 1100; i < 20000; i++) {
    stmt.addBatch("insert into student (id, name) values (1100+i, 
        'yang"+i"') ");
}
stmt.executeBatch();
con.commit();
```

Comment: `stmt.addBatch("insert into student (id, name) values ("+1100+i"+, 
        'yang"+i"') ");` Anyway string concatenation is poor idea. You should use parameters instead.

Comment: I'am a noob,how can i use paras in java.sql.Statement?

Comment: and..this codes also doesn't work QAQ

Answer (score 2):

You're using `i` **inside** the string, just like you're using `values` or `insert` inside the string. So naturally the text `i` is sent to the database, which doesn't have a column or identifier for it.

Instead, use a prepared statement and `setInt`:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into student (id, name) values (?, ?)");
for (int i = 1100; i < 20000; i++) {
    ps.setInt(1, 1100 + i); // Or I think you may just want `i`, not `1100 + i`
    ps.setString(2, "yang" + i);
    ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
con.commit();
```

---

Let me introduce to you [my friend Bobby](https://bobby-tables.com/):

[image]

**Don't** use string concatenation to put values in SQL strings. First, it's easy to mess it up (as in this case). Second, it's insecure unless you do a lot of work to ensure the resulting string is clean (which is easy to mess up).

Comment: @duckzz1 - Using a variable in a string is fairly basic, there's an example in the `setString` call above. But again, never do it to create the SQL. Just the parameters you're passing to the statement via the `setXyz` methods.